# Control route based on cookie value in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, cookies, routes, laravel-7

I am trying to set the language directory of the URL based on a cookie.

In `routes/web.php` I added this test route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $cookie = cookie('language', 'fr', 120);
    //do some logic to specify locale based on cookie value 
    $lang = Cookie::get('language');
    return 'Langauge ='.$lang;
});
```

But that code does not create any cookie. And when I check it later in the same route file:

```
if (Cookie::get('language') !== null) {
    //do something
}
```

I simple don't get anything.

Is it possible that I can create and read cookie from route?
If it's not the right place, how can I detect cookie value on each page load to use that value in my route?

(P.S. I've seen some asking the same question, but there's no good answer).

**Update**

So my real route will look like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getHomeData')->name('home');    
});
```

How can I basically save the cookie and attach it to the output?

Comment: sounds like something a middleware would be useful for

Comment: Interesting! so I create the cookie in the middleware, but how to check the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set `cookie` value and sent with a response. And you can retrieve that `cookie` value in any subsequent `request()` from your route or in controller method. Here is an example

```
 Route::get('/set-cookie', function () {
    return response('Cookie set successfully')->cookie('language', 'fr', 120);
 });
 Route::get('/get-cookie', function () {
    return request()->cookie('language');
 });
```

In your controller method

```
 public function index(){
    return response(view('welcome'))->withCookie(cookie('language', 'fr', 120));
 }
```

And you can retrieve on your `welcome.blade.php` as

```
{{ request()->cookie('language') ?? 'No cookie set '}}
```

Comment: What are these /set-cookie and /get-cookie routes coming from?

Comment: These route are used here for demonstration only. You can call your route as you want

Comment: Yes sorry, so what if I want to create the cookie first, outside the route group? how can I attach with an output of controller function? I will update the question for more details.

Comment: edited as you want @Lamar. if you find this answer helpful,please accept it as an answer. It will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems like I'm doing a terrible job explaining myself. So let me ask you this. how can I redirect to proper url after set-cookie route is called ?

Comment: [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirects)

Comment: Honestly that didn't answer my real problem, but your set cookie helped me shape my next question, hence the mark as answer. Yet I'm creating a new more specific question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in the controller.

This is how you set cookie,

```php
    $cookie = cookie('language', 'fr', 120);

    return response('done')->cookie($cookie);
```

This is how you get it.

```php
    $value = request()->cookie('language');

    return response($value);
```